# Esri leaflet functionality

Tags: esri-leaflet

Can you do client side spatial analysis with Esri leaflet?

For example:

- Buffer, project, and simplify geometry.
- Calculate areas and lengths for geometry.
- Determine spatial relations.
- Determine distances between geometries.
- Apply Union, Intersection, and Difference operations between geometries.
- Auto Complete, Generalize, Reshape, Offset, Trim/Extend, and compute Convex Hulls of geometries.

Comment: As per the [Tour], our focussed Q&A format works best with one question per question.  Although you have only placed one question mark (which is good) you are effectively asking almost 20 questions of the form "can you X with Esri leaflet?" and so I think you should research/ask each separately.

Comment: You should probably review the Frequently Asked Questions at https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet

Comment: i vote this question be reopened based on my edit.  while still broad, there is a generic relevant answer  (which is 'not directly, but possible with the help of additional leaflet plugins')

Comment: @JohnGravois That sounds reasonable so I have re-opened.

Answer (score 2):

The [Esri Leaflet](http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/) plugin does not provide this capability directly.

However, it already does the heavy lifting of converting Esri [Geoservices](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Geometry_objects/02r3000000n1000000/) JSON into [GeoJSON](http://geojson.io/#map=2/20.0/0.0) for clientside display.

This means that it plays nicely with [TurfJS](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/), which includes functions for measuring, buffering, calculating convex hulls, unioning and statistics.

In the ArcGIS API for JavaScript, you can find comparable functionality in the local [geometryEngine](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.geometry.geometryengine-amd.html) (new in [3.13](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/whats_new.html))